# New console windows crash Explorer.exe and Windows desktop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Recently I am interested in programming a windows batch file.

In this process, I found a critical problem in programming CMD batch.

Many CMD batch windows cause crashing explorer.exe and Windows desktop.

Many odd symptoms on Window desktop occurred.

Thus, I must kill explorer.exe and restart explorer.exe

#### Example

**A.cmd:**

```
@echo off
set /a a=0

:loop
set /a a=%a%+1
echo %a%
timeout /t 2 > nul
start B.cmd
goto loop
```

**B.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo Hello, WORLD !!!
timeout /t 60 > nul
exit
```

I executed **A.cmd**.

After a while, windows screen crashed.

Someone said that's hardware spec problem.
Someone said that's loop batch problem.
Someone said that's malware problem.

I don't think that's a computer, malware and hardware spec problem.

I think Microsoft windows itself problem.

The batch file that I am think of must need many (1~30) new CMD windows that will closed after a while.

Thus I made a CMD batch file.

No problem.

Working well.

The only problem is crashing Explorer.exe with crashing Windows desktop.

What's the solution?

Comment: Every two seconds you start a new cmd which runs for 60 seconds. After one minute, when cmd30 starts, cmd01 closes (keeping 29 running). After two minutes, when cmd02 closes, you are starting cmd60, (keeping 58 running) and so on. There is a point when you get a resource problem (MainMemory), running too much cmd windows.

Comment: My computer have 16GB RAM.

Comment: I don't think insufficient memory causes this problem. Actually, CMD batch don't require much memory. View task manager. resouces are enough.

Comment: There are more limitations than free RAM (in blocks of variable size). The number of processes running parallel, handles, [user objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486.aspx), [GDI objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291.aspx), etc. are also limited by Windows. All "global resources" are managed by Windows in static tables for efficiency and therefore an "out of resource" can easily happen even with just a single application running if it creates in a loop new global resources without deletion.

Comment: For example the number of timers running parallel is not unlimited and your batch construction creates permanently new timers. Those timers are of course managed globally to send an event to timeout.exe if it's associated timer timed out. See for example [How many Windows handles in use is “too many”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951419/)

Comment: Thanks, mofi . I heard it. I was disappointed at programming CMD batch. My batch file is not a complicated file.Very simple. But MS windows screen is crashed so frequently and so easily. I can't understand it. Actually 30 IE windows are OK. 30 chrome windows are also OK. Only many CMD windows cause th problem. Thus I can't understand it.

Comment: @NewB Can you verify that 30 cmd windows (not running your batch files) causes the symptoms you're seeing or does the problem only occur when your batch files are running? I can run 25-50 CMD windows simultaneously without seeing any problems on Win7 and Win8.

Comment: This behaviour is not normal.  I would suspect either malware or badly-designed third-party software.  (There are other, less likely, possibilities, including problems with the video drivers.)

Comment: @mojo Yes, I can.Sometimes it looks like normal. But After a while, the problem occurs. No malware. No hardware problem. No third party software. I tested with many computers and virtual machines.All the same. If it occurs because of a bad video driver, testing with virtual machines must be OK. But it occurs with virtual machines. Here is a video. http://tvpot.daum.net/clip/ClipView.do?clipid=63964418&rtes=y&startDuration=0

Comment: I edited A.cmd. explorer "http :// www. google.com"(no new tab, new window option) instead of start B.cmd. After 10 minutes, No problem. Everything is OK. This is the reason that I say cmd windows cause  the problem.

Comment: Doesn't occur on my machine.  OTOH, it looks like you're running an outdated version of Windows, and a foreign language variant at that, which could make a difference.  I see that the hung window has a title bar; what does the title say?

Comment: That's a explorer windows. I will test with English windows 7. I tested with a foreign language Windows 7 & windows 8.

Comment: Yes, but what *sort* of Explorer window?  It appeared spontaneously, as far as I could see, and it was the only part of Explorer that was hung, so that's where the problem lies.  Can you translate the text in the title bar?

Comment: Recently I installed English MS windows. And I tested it. No problem. In conclusion, I guess foreign language fonts of foreign MS windows cause this problem. Thanks Everyone.