# Adding about 4000 or more controls in a panel in winforms creating Error Creating window handle

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a forms, where I want to add about thousands of labels but It always give exception for creating window handle.
I am disposing some of the labels and create some more Controls but I cant found any workaround on this.

I am disposing them as:

```
track.Tablature.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList().Where(t => getNotes.Select(z => z).Contains(t.Name) || getLabels.Contains(t.Tag) || getLabels.Contains(t.Name) || getLabels.Contains(t.Name)).ToList().ForEach(z =>
            {                
                track.Tablature.Controls.Remove(z);
                z.Dispose();
            });
            
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWRr1.png)
Atleast it should allow me to add 10000 controls but it gives error at 4500 controls

Comment: Can you share the error details?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944471/how-many-controls-can-i-create-and-show-in-a-windows-forms-form

Comment: If you are adding 1000s of anything to a windows form, you are likely doing the wrong thing. Even if it did work, the invalidation and redraw would be a killer

Comment: My Ryzen 7-5800X Windows 10-x64 16GB with VS2017 .NET Framework 4.7.2 crash at 9972 labels using `for 10000 add new label`. Take a look at [Windowless controls are not magic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050211-00/?p=36473) • [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/ba-p/723848) • [How to increase windows UI resource limit](https://www.epiusers.help/t/how-to-increase-windows-ui-resource-limit/51905/2) • [GDI Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects)

Comment: @OlivierRogier you need more ram, just saying... 16gig is so 2004 :)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951419/1997232) (since every control in winforms is a window).

Comment: *"thousands of labels"* may be a poor solution. Does the user needs so many at once? I doubt so. For lists there are dedicated controls and you may even use virtualization to reduce impact.

Comment: @OlivierRogier haha, your lack of ram is clouding your judgment. http://www.scarm.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/OutOfMemory.png

Comment: 10000 is the maximum number of handles you can create. After that, the System may decide it's time to terminate the application, it's clearly misbehaving. -- `Controls.Clear()` doesn't *clear* anything, it just removes the references of **existing** Controls from a collection. All created Controls are still very well alive (so are their handles). There's no possible reason to crate so many Controls. Wrong design.

Comment: This is waaaay too much.  Period. No workarounds. - You may look into a DataGridView or a ListView or into GDI+ DrawString. What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: I am updating my question, I was meant that i Atleast want to add 10000 controls but it generate errors at around 4000 controls

Comment: You can't do that with Winforms. Period. And you really should not need that either. Thousands of controls are always a design/UI error

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects regarding max GDI handles and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/user-objects regarding max User Handles which pertain to your situation. It is not necessarily always 10000 as others have stated.